# Get values with the key names from json object

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the values from specific columns from the python list object. This is the response format from Log analytics API here - https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API/ResponseFormat

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "Category",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "count_",
                    "type": "long"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "Administrative",
                    20839
                ],
                [
                    "Recommendation",
                    122
                ],
                [
                    "Alert",
                    64
                ],
                [
                    "ServiceHealth",
                    11
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There are hundreds of columns and i want to read specific columns and row values. To do that, i initially tried to find an index for the column for e.g., "Category" and retrieve all the values from rows. Here is what i have done so far.

```
result=requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
index_category = (result.json()['tables'][0]['columns']).index('Category')
```

result contains data in the format posted above. I get this below error. What am i missing?

> `ValueError: 'Category' is not in list`

I want to be able to retrieve the Category values from rows array in a loop. I have also done this below loop and i am able to get what i want but want to confirm if there is a better way to do this. Also i am retrieving the column index first before reading the row value because i suspect blindly reading the row values with explicit index values is prone to error, particularly when the sequence of columns change.

```
for column in range(0,columns):
    if ((result.json()['tables'][0]['columns'][column]['name']) == 'Category'):
        index_category = column

for row in range(0,rows):
    print(result.json()['tables'][0]['rows'][row][index_category])
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this question was downvoted. I think i explained the problem and also shared the steps i took and also the solution i had come up with. Curious to learn so i can ask better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_data = results.json()

for index, columns in enumerate(json_data['tables'][0]['columns']):
   if columns['name'] == 'Category':
      category_index = index
      break

category_list = []
for row in json_data['tables'][0]['rows']:
    category_list.append(row[category_index])
```

Haven't tested it btw.

You could also refactor the first loop where we find the index for the category with the filter function.

Comment: Thanks @alex067 this definitely helped.

Comment: Glad it has helped. Please mark it as the answer so it may help others as well